# Jquery click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to give some functionality to my button using jquery `click` function. But when i run the code the function wouldn't get invoke at all.

My code is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
     $("#min").click(function(e){
         $("#listFriends").css('display','none');
         $("#friendsO").show();
     });
 </script>
```

And

```
<button id="min">[-]</button>
```

Please anyone tell me what mistake I made in this code.....Thanks..........

Comment: Does the button exists when you are binding the event?

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Leclerc yes otherwise how I click on the button

Comment: You could load the button in ajax or added to the dom AFTER the event is bound to the element.

Comment: Would you paste your whole page?

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Leclercr below answer was solved my problem Thanks........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `});` for closing document ready handler.

```
$(function() {
   $("#min").click(function(e){
      console.log('test');
      $("#listFriends").hide();
      $("#friendsO").show();
   });
}); // <----
```

If you generate the element dynamically you should delegate the event, from one of static parents of the element or `document` object:

```
$(document).on('click', "#min", function(e){
      console.log('test');
      $("#listFriends").hide();
      $("#friendsO").show();
});
```

Comment: @james Do you see any error on the console? Have you included jQuery library?

Comment: No errors nothing... I'm adding this button with jQuery.. Is that cause anything for this problem...

Comment: @james You are welcome. Because when you try to select the element that element doesn't exist on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Install firebug on firefox and enable debug, see [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/).